# Passing json to Flash AS3

Tags: php, json, flash

I'm trying to load a json from my php into flash. It works but i've a little problem. I want to send a GET method of posting to the php. If i change the `jsurl` bit in my code it works but when i change it to this `"http://localhost/Omega/common/flash.php?AppID="+ AppID +"&&formid="+FormID;` it doesn't work any longer.

```
var temp:Object;
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var jsurl:String;

if(myLoaderInfo.loaderComplete){

  jsurl = "http://localhost/Omega/common/flash.php?AppID="+ AppID +"&&formid="+FormID;
  loader.load(new URLRequest(jsurl));
  loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
}
```

In my php file I've something like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['AppID']) && isset($_GET['formid'])){

  $id = $_GET['AppID'];
  $uni = $_GET['formid'];

}else{

  $id = "SOS-00002";
  $uni = "UNI-00002";

}

   $q = sprintf("SELECT * FROM UNI WHERE UNI.studentid= %s AND UNI.uni_id= %s", GetSQLValueString($id,    "text"),GetSQLValueString($uni, "text"));
   $rs = mysql_query($q);
   $var = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);
   sendResponse(200, json_encode($var));
   return true;
```

I've also specified my the params being passed to my .swf file like this:

```
<param name="movie" value="WebForm.swf?AppID=<?php echo $_GET['AppID']; ?>&&FormID=<?php echo $_GET['FormID']; ?>&&resultsArray=<?php fillFlashData($_GET['AppID'], $_GET['FormID']); ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it. Looks like I wasn't calling my variables `AppID` and `FormID` right in Flash

I was loading my variables in Flash like this:

```
var AppID, FormID;
var resultsArray:Object;
function loaderComplete(myEvent:Event)
{
    this.myParams=this.loaderInfo.parameters;
    this.myParamsLoaded=true;
    this.useParams();
}

function useParams()
{
    AppID=this.myParams.AppID;
    FormID=this.myParams.FormID;
    resultsArray=this.myParams.resultsArray;
}
```

Changed that to:

```
var paramObj:Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters.AppID;
var paramObj1:Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters.FormID;

jsurl = "http://localhost/Omega/common/flash.php?AppID="+ paramObj.toString() +"&&formid="+paramObj1.toString();
loader.load(new URLRequest(jsurl));
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
```

And it works perfectly now.